# Custom posts categories are merging with each other

Tags: wordpress

I have created 2 custom posts in my website, Now the problem is whenever I am creating any category in the first custom post it`s automatically add in second custom post, I want separate categories for every custom posts.

Maybe i am doing something wrong in creating custom posts...?

Please help...

Below is the code

```
function create_posttype()
{
    register_post_type( 'case_study',

        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Case Study' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Case Study' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'case_study'),
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
            'supports' => array( 'title','thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields','editor', 'post-templates', 'related-post', 'thumbnail','excerpt'),
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'healthcare',

        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Health care' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Health care' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'healthcare'),
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
            'supports' => array( 'title','thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields','editor', 'post-templates', 'related-post', 'thumbnail','excerpt'),
        )
    );
}

// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

function add_case_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box("case_contact_meta", "case_study", "add_contact_details_team_meta_box", "case_study", "normal", "low");
}
function add_contact_details_team_meta_box()
{
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
?>
    <p>
        <label>Designation: </label><br />
        <input type="text" name="designation" value="<?= @$custom["designation"][0] ?>" class="width99" />
    </p>
    <p>

    <?php
}

function save_case_custom_fields(){
  global $post;

  if ( $post )
  {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "designation", @$_POST["designation"]);
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_case_meta_boxes' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_case_custom_fields' );

/****************/

function add_healthcare_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box("healthcare_contact_meta", "healthcare", "add_healthcare_meta_box", "healthcare", "normal", "low");
}
function add_healthcare_meta_box()
{
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
?>
    <p>
        <label>Designation: </label><br />
        <input type="text" name="designation" value="<?= @$custom["designation"][0] ?>" class="width99" />
    </p>
    <p>

    <?php
}

function save_healthcare_custom_fields(){
  global $post;

  if ( $post )
  {
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "designation", @$_POST["designation"]);
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_healthcare_meta_boxes' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_healthcare_custom_fields' );
```

Thanks in advance.... :-)

Comment: why are you wrapping it in a function create_posttype()? did you used the code in functions.php?

Comment: @charankumar Yes

Comment: remove the create_posttype function and try

Comment: @charankumar still the same problem. :(

Comment: You can see your answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168612/create-category-only-for-custom-post-type?answertab=active#tab-top